# Windows 2003 - logging off the Administrator account makes web applications inaccessible

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-server

Consider a web application installed on a Windows Server 2003 SP2 machine with the admin account. The application is accessible in the server as well as in the network when at least one session of the admin account is logged in. If there are no active sessions of the admin account, the web application is not accessible via the network, nor accessible locally when logged in with another user account.

What would cause the web application to be inaccessible there's no Administrator session?

Please suggest anything that might help find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting this web application?

Edit:

> From comment: through IE, xx.xx.xx.xx/clientname/0/System/Session/Login.asp sorry if had misunderstood your question.

So it is running under IIS, not as a separate executable launched within the login session.

Next things to do:

1. What user identity is being used by IIS to run it?
2. Is there anything in the event log? E.g. failures from IIS, login failures from the user identity, ...

To determine #1 use "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" (from administration tools). Go to the root of the web application matching the URL (this might be the folder containing `login.asp`, or an ancestor: look for a folder with a gearicon). Open up the properties and go to the Virtual Directory tab. Look at the Application Name. Go to the Application Pools and look at the properties of the node named for the application name. The identity tab will tell you which user account is being used to run the web application.

Comment: through IE, http://xx.xx.xx.xx/clientname/0/System/Session/Login.asp

sorry if had misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi Richard

As our's is an IIS 5 based application, we have set the Web sites -> services property to run in "Run WWW/ service in IIS Isolation mode". Becuase of this property the application pool property has disappeared and Application protection is enabled.

Comment: @Saravana... and under 2003 it is IIS6 which included a lot of security changes. You really need to break out the (remote) debugger and do lots of logging to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be running the application as admin. Use a separate account, preferably one that has only just enough access to do what it needs to do. Then make sure it's running as a service, not an application.